# If $a_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $a_n=(\frac{2n-3}{2n})a_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 2$, then show that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k <1$

Tags: real-analysis

A sequence of numbers $a_n, n=1,2,...$ is defined as follows:

$a_1=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $a_n=\left(\dfrac{2n-3}{2n}\right)a_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 2$.

Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k <1$ for all $n \ge 1$

Using the relation, we can work out $\displaystyle a_n=\dfrac{C(2n,n)}{(2n-1)4^n}$

Additionally, $\dfrac{C(2n,n)}{(2n-1)4^n} \le \dfrac{1}{2n-1}$

Now, I am stuck at how to prove t

Answer (score 2):

A direct solution is to prove the explicit formula $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=1-\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$ using induction on $n$.

In fact $a_n=(-1)^{n-1}\binom{1/2}{n}$ understood in the [extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series) sense, so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n=1-\sqrt{1-z}$ when $|z|<1$, and even when $|z|\leqslant 1$ by [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). This gives an alternative way to see $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=\tfrac14$ in$$\sum_{n\ge1}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^n}{2n-1}=2\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!^2}\frac{x^n}{n}=2\int_0^x\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(2k)!}{k!^2}t^kdt=2\int_0^x(1-4t)^{-1/2}dt$$to evaluate the infinite series as $[-(1-4t)^{1/2}]_0^{1/4}=1$, which will be strictly greater than each partial sum.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of *Mathematica*
$$a_n=\frac{\Gamma \left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi } \;\Gamma (k+1)}.$$
and
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\Gamma \left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi }\; \Gamma (k+1)}=1.$$
Thus
$$\sum _{k=1}^{n }a_n<1$$